# Asynchronous Requests Error "object of type 'method' has no len()" - Python, BS4 & asyncio/aiohttp

Tags: asynchronous, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Hi so I'm working on a web scraper that loops through a list of URLS and returns true if the URL is not owned by an active users account, and false if the URL is in use by an account. The process was too slow with the requests library so I opted to use asyncio and aiohttp instead to run the scraper asynchronously. However I'm at a part in my code where I am receiving the following error: `elif len(markup) <= 256 and ( TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()`. The console states the error is due to lines 33, 44, and 49, but I have no idea why this error is thrown. Another user suggested it may be due [to missing brackets in my calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57302245/14743524), but I have called all functions correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The error comes from the beautiful soup library, when I debug it. I'm not sure how to correct this in my code

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

with

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
```

Please read [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.text) carefully.

Comment: HAHAHHAHA THANK YOU SO MUCH - Sorry for the caps. Thanks man. This is great, really appreciate your response - pardon the pun.